# Detect @ character onKeyUp in Edge on any keyboard

Tags: javascript, keyboard, microsoft-edge

In most browsers on my qwerty keyboard, `event.key` of shift + 2 is "@" from the keyup key event. However, Edge reports `event.key: "2"`. So I could just put down something like

```
if(event.key == "2" && event.shiftKey){
  //code to execute when "@" key is down
}
```

which works great until one a user with a keyboard from a country like Germany or Hungary, or probably many others comes and expects my code to work on Edge when they type an "@" character but instead of shift + 2, they use some other key combination.

**How can I reliably detect the "@" character from an onKeyUp event in Edge given that some keyboard layouts do not produce an @ character from shift + 2?**

Is there a way to detect that a user is using a keyboard that has an alternate layout and is there some list of layouts from which I could create some probably obscenely long switch statement to map the "shift + 2" code for any given combo per keyboard layout?

I need this to work in onKeyUp, not onKeyDown.

This is what Edge gives me with shift + 2 onkeyup.

```
[object KeyboardEvent]: {altKey: false, bubbles: true, cancelable: true, cancelBubble: false, charCode: 0...}
altKey: false
bubbles: true
cancelable: true
cancelBubble: false
charCode: 0
ctrlKey: false

currentTarget: Object
defaultPrevented: false
detail: 0
eventPhase: 3
isTrusted: true
key: "2"
keyCode: 50
location: 0
metaKey: false
repeat: false
returnValue: true
shiftKey: true

srcElement: Object

target: Object
timeStamp: 69676.72914431277
type: "keyup"

view: Object
which: 50

__proto__: Object
```

Below is an image of a German keyboard. Note the position of the @ char. I don't want to support just German and American, I want to support any keyboard.

[image: German keyboard]

On Edge in onKeyUp, event.charCode is always 0, event.key is 2 even when the shift key is down when trying to type @, and event.char is always undefined. See this Codepen as a starting place using the Edge browser: https://codepen.io/glenpierce/pen/QmNQRq?editors=1111#

Comment: Have you considered using `event.charCode`? Edge still supports that property and it provides the UTF-8 character code. One would not think that would be different between keyboards.

Comment: `event.charCode` in onKeyUp always seems to be 0 on Edge.

Comment: bummer - I believed the docs! :-/ Anyway, getting the UTF code point or charCode seems like the _safest_ solution.

Answer (score 4):

You can test this:

Edit:
If we are looking for @ char
(which its not always shift + 2)

```
//in edge is char, the rest has character in key. In some cases you can use charCode
if(event.key == '@' || event.char == '@' || event.charCode == '@') {

 }
```

Comment: This will work but you don't need the *if event.shiftKey*-part to only detect the "@"

Comment: @MarkusMadeja actually we need even remove if(shiftKey) in some keyboard layouts @ short key is: alt+ctl+q

Comment: In onKeyUp, event.charCode is always 0, event.key is 2 even when the shift key is down, and event.char is undefined. codepen.io/glenpierce/pen/QmNQRq?editors=1111#

Comment: @GlenPierce as you see the @ is under q and I mentioned, it would be (alt gr+q) or other combination of key + q

Comment: That's true, but this code fails on an American keyboard.

Comment: Could you console.log event in American keyboard? I think it would be two events (one gives 2 and the other one should give you the @ char in key or char element)

Answer (score 0):

This approach has compatibility problems across browsers, the safest way is to use `keypress` event instead of `keyup` and check:

```
document.addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
  var at_code = event.DOM_VK_AT || 64;
  if (event.keyCode === at_code || event.charCode === at_code || event.key === '@')
    console.log("@ Pressed");
});
```

Comment: onKeyUp is a requirement.

Answer (score -1):

To support all keyboards with Edge (IE) you need to use the value set in the `KeyboardEvent.charCode` property instead of attempting to interpret the key code.

This code will suffice for only Edge & Chrome:

```
document.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
    if (event.charCode === '@') {
        //
    }
});
```

But to support all browsers, I would use:

```
document.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
    if (event.charCode === '@' || event.key === '@' || event.char === '@') {
        //
    }
});
```

Source: [`KeyboarEvent.keyCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) (deprecated) and [`KeyboardEvent.key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key)

Comment: In onKeyUp, event.charCode is always 0, event.key is 2 even when the shift key is down, and event.char is undefined. https://codepen.io/glenpierce/pen/QmNQRq?editors=1111#

Comment: hum... That's interesting. What version of Edge are you running?

Answer (score -1):

You can try a regular expression like this

```
$(".detectAt").on("keyup", function(){
      e = e || event;
    var regex= /[^@]/i;

   return regex.test(String.fromCharCode(e.charCode || e.keyCode));
});
```

Comment: charCode is always 0. keyCode is 2 on American keyboards, and could be anything on another keyboard.